# ImportError: cannot import name 'UserUpdateForm' from 'register.forms'

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

i am beginner to the django and i am getting this error while loading server.So please help

This is my register/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'register/profile.html', context)
```

This is my register/signal.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

This is register/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class RegisterConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'register'
    def ready(self):
        import register.signals
```

The error its showing is from here = from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm

Please have a look what i am doing wrong..

Comment: Your `register.forms` modlule has no `UserUpdateForm`, that is what the error is complaining about. Even if it has a `UserRegisterForm`, you are importing "too much".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `forms.py` only has a `UserRegisterForm`. The error complains about the fact that it can not import the `UserUpdateForm` (and likely if you remove that, it will complain about the `ProfileUpdateForm`, since that is not defined either). You can fix the problem with the `UserUpdateForm` by importing it from the `django.contrib.auth.forms` module, and *re-export* it. For `ProfileUpdateForm`, you will need to implement additional forms:

```
# register/forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserUpdateForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ['user']
```

Comment: what about putting fields = ['image']  unde profileupdateform class ?

Comment: @AvinashDwivedi: you can implement the `ProfileUpdateForm` in a different way. The above was just an example how to add the extra classes.